# How do you find an object in a list with a specific property using Lambda operators?

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to understand Lambda operators... here's what I've got so far.

I have a `List<Record>` named `record_list`. I want to remove the `Record` from our list that has a `Record.UserName` property of `USER1`.

```
record_list.Remove(record_list.Where(r = r.UserName.ToString() == "USER1"))
```

Obviously I misunderstand something, but I think I'm close.

The error I'm getting is:

> cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Client_SCM_2.Record>` to `Client_SCM_2.Record`

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try to get the record first then remove it from the list if it exists

```
var record = record_list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.UserName.ToString() == "USER1");
if(record != null) {
   record_list.Remove(record);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code would return IEnumerable

```
var User1List = record_list.Where(x => x.UserName.ToString() == "USER1"));
```

To get your object, use First() or FirstOrDefault()

Then delete the record

```
var recordToBeDeleted = User1List.FirstOrDefault();
if(recordToBeDeleted != null) //null means no record found
{
    record_list.Remove(recordToBeDeleted )
}
```

If you want to remove all the records matching predicate, use [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx/)

```
record_list.RemoveAll(x => x.UserName.ToString() == "USER1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
record_list.RemoveRange(record_list.Where(r => r.UserName.ToString() == "USER1"))
```

I thionk you needed RemoveRange
Also, you were missing a > for the Lambda.

Hope this helps